# Android Check if network signal strength is low

Tags: android, signal-strength

I am working on an android app which keeps checking my location using GPS and automatically stops recording if not moving for more than 3 mins. 
But sometimes may be due to poor signal it is not able to stop automatically.

is there anyway to determine the poor network signal in my android code ?
I have seen few posts on PhoneStateListener but how to check if the signal is poor in android code.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post your code, so I assume you have a `WifiManager` object, using that you can request a `getConnectionInfo()` method. Along with it, you should create a class that extends `BroadcastReceiver` which will implement `onReceive` where you can get a list of `ScanResult` there you'll get all info about your network including the signal strength.

This [link](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/40.html), will help you.